# has AspectJ execution in thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, aspectj, aspect

Knowledge question = no code, no error, no examples to reports.

I applied a joinpoint over `method()` of `ClassA`, and `ClassA` is not a singleton. I create `MyAspect` that handle this joinpoint.

Question: if there are 2 callers of `ClassA.method()`, and callers works on 2 different threads (e.g. web requests ), AspectJ will run `MyAspect` over the 2 different threads or in a single one ?

I think that AspectJ execute `MyAspect` in the same thread of woven class (`ClassA` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

AspectJ will execute your aspects on the current thread. That means, if you have a multi-threaded execution, your aspect will run on multiple threads as well. If your aspect works with shared state, you'll need to make sure about accessing your shared state in a safe way.

Also note that there are other aspect instantiation models besides the default *singleton*. With a singleton aspect, only one instance of the aspect will be created in your app. You could use the `perthis()`, `pertarget()`, `percflow()` or `percflowbelow()` modifiers which changes how your aspect will get instantiated, and AspectJ will create a new instance of your aspect on a *per-object* or *per-control-flow* basis. You might be able to isolate aspect state with these instantiation models, but if you're using *shared* state, the basic rule still applies: you need to take care about thread-safe access to the shared state.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestions.